# How can I access the enumeration OracleDbType?

Tags: c#, oracle

My C# (.NET 4.0) application is calling a stored procedure in a PL/SQL database. I have added the namespace System.Data.OracleClient, and added the parameters however whenever I run it, I get an exception saying parameters don't match.

I believe the issue is because my parameters have been of type DbType.String or OracleType.VarChar. Reading online revealed that people use another enumeration called OracleDbType (eg. OracleDbType.VarChar2).

So, how can I access this enumeration?

```
 OracleParameter returnParam = new OracleParameter("result", DbType.Xml);
            returnParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(returnParam);

            OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter("pivequivalentinstrument", DbType.String);
            param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param1.Value = EquivalentInstrKey;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [OracleDbType](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm) is [ODP: Oracle.DataAccess.Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) not the [deprecated System.Data.OracleClient](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx), try using ODP and it shall be there.

Comment: Yep. This enumeration is part of Oracle® Data Provider for .NET. See [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to cast your parameter directly to an `OracleParameter` to access the `OracleDbType` property.

Comment: I believe my parameters are of type OracleParamter. See original question. I've added some code.

Comment: @xbonez: Then your `param1` object, for example, should have an `OracleDbType` property. Does it not?

Comment: Nope. The only options I have are OracleType and DbType.